# javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /: Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: jsf, facelets

Getting this kind of error.

```
2020-05-29 01:38:29,519 ERROR [stderr] (default task-20) javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /: Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog.
2020-05-29 01:38:29,519 ERROR [stderr] (default task-20) at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:456)
2020-05-29 01:38:29,519 ERROR [stderr] (default task-20) at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:430)
2020-05-29 01:38:29,519 ERROR [stderr] (default task-20) at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
```

The below is what i have used..

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"     
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"            
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"                    
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">....................</ui:composition>
```

Please help me to solve this out.!

Comment: Post the error in a search enging en investigate...

Comment: Thanks.. But I don't find something similar/relatable to solve my error.

Comment: [ask] states to search and tell why it it not help. There are for sure dozens related questions and answers. Find them, read them add them to the question and mention for each of them why it did not help or whybyour case isi dfferent.

Comment: And how do you know the error is about this xhtml file? Checked (like mentioned in one of the llinks from the search results if replacing ' with " in `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>` fixes things?

Comment: I don't have this issue in my local server. only when I tried opening the module in portal server got this with xhtml. 
And it points line:1 ` <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>`  and even I tried the single quotes with double quotes but still this **javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /: Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog.** 
And I haven't used any ` / ` at line:1 :(

Comment: I had got this one fixed. xhtml file name was not passed, while invoking it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the "`<!-- -->`"-Comments within your XHTML. May cause this problem.

Comment: E.g., I had an open "<"-Bracket in my comment, what cause the problem.